# How to pass 2 parameters in then clause inside case statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm  developing a scholl project and I created a stored procedure and  need to pass two arguments inside of THEN clause, when the variable `@tempo` is day I want to select month and day.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE tentativa1 
    @tempo as nvarchar(30),
    @ap_id int
AS
    SELECT
        L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, 
        COUNT(*) AS NumeroAcessos, year,
        CASE
            WHEN @tempo = 'month' THEN month 
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS 'MES',
        CASE 
            WHEN @tempo = 'day' THEN day 
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS 'DIA'
    FROM 
        L_AccessPoint 
    INNER JOIN 
        F_Session ON L_AccessPoint.ap_id = F_Session.ap_id
    WHERE 
        L_AccessPoint.ap_id = @ap_id
    GROUP BY
        L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, year,
        CASE WHEN @tempo = 'month' THEN month ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN @tempo ='day' THEN day ELSE NULL END
    ORDER BY
        L_AccessPoint.ap_id, year,
        CASE WHEN @tempo ='month' THEN month ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN @tempo ='day' THEN day ELSE NULL END
```

Is possible to make something like that:

```
CASE 
    WHEN @tempo = 'day' THEN month, day 
    ELSE NULL 
END AS 'DIA'
```

If `@tempo` is day, I have to group by year, month and day, otherwise if `@tempo` is year I just have to group by year. If I pass `@tempo` equals to day, the result is group by year and day, grouping all of days 1 of every months inside a year in the same row. Like this [Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcVJV.png). Exists any way to do that correctly??

Comment: No, `CASE` is an **expression** not a statement, and it returns a scalar value. Plus returning 2 columns with a single alias doesn't make sense.

Comment: Simple answer: no. (@Larnu beat me to it)

Comment: @Larnu  if "tempo" is day, i need to select month and day, and if "tempo" is month i need to select only month how can i do that?
Ty for you answer.

Comment: You can't without dynamic SQL, @AlexandreLourenço . A SQL statement must be well defined.

Comment: @Larnu So it's impossible to do that?? Or exists any way to do that??

Comment: I would suggest that you control what column(s) are displayed to your end user are done in the presentation layer, @AlexandreLourenço .

Comment: @Larnu i need to do some type of validation here,because if i dont do the validation here i will have a problem, if "tempo" is day i have to group by year, month and day, otherwise if "tempo" is year i just have to group by year. If i pass "tempo" equals to day, the result is group by year and day, grouping all of days 1 of every months inside a year in the same row. Like this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/933112660051001385/955521269506383902/unknown.png , but i need to group by month too, its possible to do that using case or other thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some testing i could make that procedure correctly, by replacing case when with if and else if, and the result stay like that:

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE testeSessoes
        @tempo as nvarchar(30),
        @data_ini as date,
        @data_fin as date
AS
BEGIN
IF @tempo = 'year'
Begin
Select L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, COUNT(*) AS NumeroAcessos, year
FROM L_AccessPoint INNER JOIN F_Session ON L_AccessPoint.ap_id = F_Session.ap_id
WHERE F_Session.ts between @data_ini and @data_fin 
Group by    L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, year
order by L_AccessPoint.ap_id ASC, year DESC
END
ELSE
IF @tempo='month'
Begin
Select L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, COUNT(*) AS NumeroAcessos, year,month
FROM L_AccessPoint INNER JOIN F_Session ON L_AccessPoint.ap_id = F_Session.ap_id
WHERE F_Session.ts between @data_ini and @data_fin
Group by    L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, year,month
order by L_AccessPoint.ap_id ASC, year DESC,month DESC
END
else
Begin
Select L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, COUNT(*) AS NumeroAcessos, year,month,day
FROM L_AccessPoint INNER JOIN F_Session ON L_AccessPoint.ap_id = F_Session.ap_id
WHERE F_Session.ts between @data_ini and @data_fin
Group by    L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, year,month,day
order by L_AccessPoint.ap_id ASC, year DESC,month DESC,day DESC
END
END
```

With that I create 3 queries that returns and group by exactly like I want.

Thanks everyone that tried to help me.